# How to force delays on starting each thread while using Grid?

Tags: grid, pom.xml, timedelay

I try to run in paralel TestSuites using Grid. This is part of my pom.xml.
How can I force 2sec delays between threads startings? Here are 4 threads max and only 3 Suites to run, so all 3 of them are started at the same time. 
After starting node with:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role webdriver -hub
http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5556 -browser
browserName=chrome,version=23,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=4
```

it causes 2 of 3 instances conflict in app due to some known reasons. It is required at least 2 sec diff in thread strating time.
How can it be done?

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>              
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>         
            <execution>
                <id>integration-test-chrome</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>    
            </execution>          
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
            <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            <includes>
                <include>**/HomeSuiteWithoutFailedTests.java</include>
                <include>**/QuotaSuiteWithoutFailedTests.java</include>
                <include>**/SpywareSuiteWithoutFailedTests.java</include>
            </includes>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <browser>${browser}</browser>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>    
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue with adding random sleep before init of driver for suite.